# error : object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, reflection

I do a reflection, in a function `func`.

Because I don't know which object I would get, I receive an object as a parameter of this function:

```
func(Object arg)
```

Now, I start with the reflection:

```
Method  method = ...
method.invoke(arg, null)
```

And I get the next error:

```
object is not an instance of declaring class
```

Comment: This is not enough code to be able to help you. Please post the method's body, the stacktrace and what value this ``Object arg`` has.

Comment: Please give more information about the error. Is it an exception? Show the complete stack trace. Also show us the implementation of the method `func`.

Comment: Can you show more actual code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message seems to be very clear: the Object `arg` is not an instance of the class to which `method` belongs. It's impossible to say how to fix this without seeing your actual code. An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `invoke` should be the object you are calling the method on.

so `someObject.callMethod(argument1);` becomes `method.invoke(someObject, argument1);`